# Passing an optional iterator to a function

Tags: c++, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

Is it possible to define an optional iterator to a function that will change the behaviour of the function based on its presence or not?

To give a concrete example consider the definition

```
template<typename Graph,
    typename random_access_iterator_distances,                        
    typename random_access_iterator_predecessors,                     
    typename back_insertor_iterator_frontier,                         
    typename back_insertor_iterator_explored >
    void dijkstra(const Graph &g,                                     
            const typename boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor source,    
            random_access_iterator_distances   distances,             
            random_access_iterator_predecessors predecessors,         
            const typename boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor target = -1,
            back_inserter_iterator_frontier frontier = null_iterator,                 
            back_inserter_iterator_explored explored = null_iterator );
```

Where the `null_iterator` would be some value that indicates the user does not want this output.

The work-around for this by defining two separate functions, one with frontier and explored in the definition, another without it, would not be a good alternative, because it would require duplication of code (since the logic in the function is tightly coupled with whether either `frontier` or `explored` is present.)

Is there somekind of pattern or replacement of `null_iterator` to make this type of code realizable in C++?

Comment: How about a `boost::optional`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Can you elaborate some more on this, this looks like a promising solution?

Comment: Well, make function argument that's a `boost::optional<my_iterator_type>`, maybe defaulted, and then the function can check whether an iterator has been passed or not.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to write a simple DevNullIterator. Since it's `operator*` doesn't do anything, it's trivially inlined and compiles away.

```
struct DevNull {
  template<typename T> operator=(T const&) { }
  template<typename T> operator T&() { static T dummy; return dummy; }
};

struct DevNullIterator {
  DevNull operator*() const { return DevNull();}
  DevNullIterator operator++() const { return *this; }
};
```

Comment: And then some algorithms might be able to further optimize with a template specialization on type `DevNullIterator` that, for example, skips some function calls which are only needed to fill that argument's output.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to define an optional iterator to a function that will change the behaviour of the function based on its presence or not?

No. This is not possible. There are two candidates;

1. Overloading. Overloading creates a new function (with the same name), so this does not meet your needs.
2. Default arguments. There is no way to distinguish whether an argument comes from the user of the function or from the default.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to KeresSB comment, I ended up coming up with what I think is a clean solution. Essentially, I use the following pattern:

```
typedef struct _undefinded {
}undefined_t;

template<typename Graph,
    typename random_access_iterator_distances,
    typename random_access_iterator_predecessors,
    typename back_inserter_iterator_frontier = undefined_t,
    typename back_inserter_iterator_explored = undefined_t >
    void dijkstra(const Graph &g,
            const typename boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor source,
            random_access_iterator_distances   distances,
            random_access_iterator_predecessors predecessors,
            const typename boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor target = -1,
            boost::optional<back_inserter_iterator_frontier> frontier = boost::optional<back_inserter_iterator_frontier>(),
            boost::optional<back_inserter_iterator_explored> explored = boost::optional<back_inserter_iterator_explored>() );
```

Then inside the code of the function, it is possible to check if either `frontier` or `explored` are defined with

```
        if ( frontier.is_initialized() ) {
        } else {
            std::cout << "frontier is uninitialized!" << std::endl;   
        }
        if ( explored.is_initialized() ) {
        } else {
            std::cout << "explored is uninitialized!" << std::endl;   
        }
```

Comment: The first typedef is a C-ism.